# What happens when two javascript events try to modify same variable at the same time

Tags: javascript

There is a javascript code that has variable `messageList` keeping the messages list and this can be updated by a function `updateMessageList()` as below:

```
var messageList=[];                           //contains list of messages
function updateMessageList(id, lastUpdate);   //updates messageList item for given id

//at some point while running
mesasgeList=[
    {id:1, lastUpdate:1371650818000},
    {id:2, lastUpdate:1371650821000},
    .....
]
```

What happens if two different sources call `updateMessageList()` function at he same time for same `messageList` item. Let's say one update for message with `id:1` comes from client (current user updating the message) and another from the server also for message with `id:1` (another user updates the message). They will both then try to access and modify `messageList[0].lastUpdate` property at the same time.

In Source 1: When the client updates the message form submit event triggers the function `handleReply()`

```
function handleReply(event) {
    .....
    var id=event.currentTarget.find('input[name="id"]').val();
    //form has an hidden input for id of the message
    var d = new Date();
    updateMessageList(id, d.getTime());
    .....
}
```

In Source 2: JS makes a AJAX call to server to check if there are any updates, and than runs`updateMessages()` function in return

```
//server sends following JSON data:{id:1, lastUpdate:1371650823269}
function updateMessages(data) {
    .....
    updateMessageList(data.id, data.lastUpdate);
    .....
}
```

The `updateMessageList()` functions will both try to change `lastUpdate` property of `messageList[0]`.

So should we think these kind of situations while programming or does javascript can handle these?

Comment: Last one wins. There's always going to be an order to execution.

Comment: We're actually asking a similar question in job interviews. It's a trick question.

Comment: If you are going to programm multithread you should lock the record on beginning of writing for writing. It's one typical problem of concurrent computing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded. There is no such thing as concurrency in javascript. One call will **always** be before or after the other. Maybe it can differ by a millisecond, but one call will exit its block before the other begins.

Comment: then if both called at the same time one of them is executed and the other one waits right?

Comment: More then one thread is actually possible in javascript http://caniuse.com/#search=worker

Comment: Web workers do not share memory. After the worker is finished, the muxer will put the pieces back together in a single-threaded fashion.

Comment: Mucahit, yes, the other one will wait. It is not defined which ove will go first. This is called "asynchronous".

Comment: Your situation is not defined. You say "two different sources call updateMessageList() function at he same time" but you do not show how that is done. So I cannot answer.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: There is no way both of these will run at the *same time*. One may happen a millisecond after the other, but they will not run at the same time. You cannot guarantee which will happen first though.

Comment: What if messageList is a very long array. Then while one is looping through it to find the right message checking on id's, the other one may be looping too. So these functions can have more complex roles. But the real important point is is that if there is a chance that both these functions does run at the same time, accessing the same variable, than I should build some mechanisms to prevent them affecting each other badly in some situations.

Comment: No, the processor gives up control at a function-level scope. That means that once a processor is in a function, it will continue until the function returns.

Comment: Is this also the situation in browsers that support multiple scripts running at the same time as abimelex stated above.

Comment: Web Workers do not share memory. They each have their own sections of memory and can not affect eachother.