# What happens when two async functions modify the same object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Related to:
[What happens when two javascript events try to modify same variable at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191886/what-happens-when-two-javascript-events-try-to-modify-same-variable-at-the-same)

But asking here because that's an old question, now we have Promises and "await" and I think could be a problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/d6k2gLu7/

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); 
}

setTimeout(async function(){
   globalArray.push(1);
   await sleep(100); 
   globalArray.push(2);
     printArray();
}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
   globalArray.push(3);
   printArray();
}, 500);
```

Without the sleep that will be 1,2,3 but with sleep in the middle it ends with 1,3,2

So we need to check again all the "global objects" after some "await"? (I'm starting to understand why is so important to use pure functions)

Comment: When manipulating higher scoped objects, the introduction of semaphores will allow things to wait until locks are released.  I think you should consider introducing semaphores in order to allow code to consistently produce the same results, irregardless of the asynchronicities being done.

Comment: what do you mean with semaphores ?

Comment: @fallenreaper Javascript is single threaded. It does not require synchronization mechanisms such as Semaphores.

Comment: @Enrique The reason people ask such a question is not to figure out what order events happen. That is self-explanatory. It is asking about simultaneous events - which is not possible and still is not possible in javascript. If it was then there is a small possibility with the right timeout values that the array will end up not with 1,3,2, but with 1,3 or 1,2 (implying that we have corrupted processing because both `.push()` have conflicting internal states) or a program crash (implying we have corrupted memory access)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is still single threaded. Therefore, there are no "thread safety" issues (e.g. 2 threads writing to the same memory location). On the other hand, Javascript functions may be executed asynchronously. Therefore, when executing several asynchronous functions, there is no guarantee to the order and when each function will start or finish (unless you use "await" and/or "then" before calling the next function).

There is a tendency to confuse between asynchronous code (for "efficiency") and multi-threaded code (for "scalability"). But really, it has two different purposes. Too many times I've observed developers adding "threads" to make their code more "efficient" (especially in Java/C++), but that's a common mistake. In many cases adding threads will not improve the efficiency of the code. (E.g. create a thread pool with 20 threads to send and handle http requests/responses concurrently).

Scalable software should often use both. Javascript, is not intended to be scalable, but definitely efficient (send and handle 20 http requests/responses concurrently works rather well in Javascript).

Comment: Yes I know is single thread, I was asking how to manage the "await" properly,I mean, every time we use await we need cannot trust in the global var anymore.

Comment: what do you mean "cannot trust" ? the only thing certain from the code is that 1 is pushed before 2. But we cannot assume anything about 3. It may be before 1 and 2,  after 1 but before 2, or maybe (less likely) after 1 and 2. The other certain thing, is that this is thread safe because only one thread is running in javascript.

Comment: @Enrique `await` doesn't change anything. In any asynchronous code you can **NEVER** use global variables to store state. That's why a lot of codes use either OOP, closures or passing around an object reference (for example, `req` and `res` in Express middlewares) to maintain state

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/sqren/await-sleep/blob/master/index.js) you have an implementation of `sleep`:

```
ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

What this means is, it's essentially a matter on who gets queued first in the [event loop](http://javascript%20event%20loop%20queue). So yes, JS is still single-threaded.

---

Clarification *(stripping out the layer of abstraction promises provide)*:

```
globalArray.push(1);
await sleep(100); 
globalArray.push(2);
```

is like writing:

```
globalArray.push(1);
setTimeout(function() {
  globalArray.push(2);
}, 100);
```

Anything can happen between the moment you `push(1)` and the moment you `push(2)`. So you can't treat your whole function as an unit that will be run entirely before anything else is run (like you could for portions of code that don't `await` nor `throw`) -- it's the whole point of it really.

Furthermore, there is no magical locking mechanism for your global array -- any locking, or checking if the values are still in order, is yours to implement.