# Could multiple JS async functions reading and modifying same variable cause race condition/unexpected variable value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I wanna keep the variable "remaining" to be >= 0. If it reaches 0, should stop doing any subtraction operation.

There are2 async functions will check the "remaining" and do subtraction if and only if >= 0.
Obviously it does work as my expectation, but I really have no idea how to solve it in the right way...

I read the article https://dev.to/loweisz/how-to-avoid-race-conditions-using-asynchronous-javascript-j30 but I am not sure if it works. Isn't same problem might still happend in between "if (!blocked) {" and "blocked = true;"?

I need help...The following is my test code

```
let remaining = 1000; // remaining should always be >= 0

const fn1 = async () => {
  console.log('fn1 invoked');

  while(remaining > 0) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // This is just a simulation of the delay between "while(remaining > 0) {" and "remaining = remaining - 1;"
        resolve();
      }, 1);
    });
    
    remaining = remaining - 1;
    console.log(`fn1 remaining: ${remaining}`);
  }
};

const fn2 = async () => {
  console.log('fn2 invoked');

  while(remaining > 0) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // This is just a simulation of the delay between "while(remaining > 0) {" and "remaining = remaining - 1;"
        resolve();
      }, 1);
    });

    remaining = remaining - 1;
    console.log(`fn2 remaining: ${remaining}`);
  }
};

/**
 * run async functions
 */
fn1();
fn2();
```

Comment: Yes, if you have an `await` between the check (`while` condition) and actual mutation of the variable (`remaining = …`), you've got a race condition. If you actually *remove* that artificial delay, it would work - synchronous sequences of statements are executed synchronously, with no parallelism.

Comment: Simplest case to show how it doesn't work: `for (let i=0; i<2000; i++) fn1();`

Comment: So in fact the artificial delay is the only cause of the race condition?

Comment: After all, in JS, there is no "running 2 functions at the same time", am I getting it right?

Comment: The cause is two async functions / promises running at the same time

Comment: @ArchitecTJ97 Yes, the *asynchronous* delay is the cause of the race condition. No two synchronous things can be executed at the same time.

Comment: @Bergi I couldn't give you a "Green Tick" here as it's in comment section. But you got my respect! Thanks again!!!

Just one more thing, If I run the JS in separate process(assumed the variable "remaining" will be stored in an external JSON to share it to multiple process to access and update"

Supposed the processes will be running in parallel? race condition could Actually happen then, right?

Comment: How exactly do you "share" the JSON storage between processes? You mean a file that you'd open from both processes, and write from both processes? Then yes, you'd have a race condition in the file accesses, and would need to use the operating system's locking functionalities.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57351137